# call spesific function php with jquery $.post url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a file with php function, called function_query.php

**function_query.php**

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root","","mydb");
function query1($connection){
   //my query
}

function query2($connection){
  //my query
}
?>
```

Then in another file called mypage.php i want post some data with jquery $.post
, but i dont know how to call the spesific function with jquery $.post , and my script is  like this

**mypage.php**

```
<?php include_once('function_query.php')?>

<button id="btn-save"> Save </button>

   <script type="text/javascript">

     $('#btn-save').on('click',function(e) {

      $.post(base_url + "function_query.php/query1", {}, function(res) {
              alert('Save!');

            });
      });
   </script>
```

When i run that script, it's doesn't error but my data isn't save to my database

How would i call that function in javascript?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add condition in your php file and get data from javascript such as $_POST['query_type'] in php file and then you can call your functions to save data on database.

your function_query.php file:

```
<?php
function query1($data){
    //your query
}
function query2($data){
    //your query
}

$query_type = $_POST['query_data'];
$data['name'] = $_POST['name']; 
$data['family'] = $_POST['family'];

if($query_type == 'insert'){
    query1($data);
} else {
    query2($data);
}
?>
```

this can be your jquery code:

```
$.post( "function_query.php", { 
    query_data: "insert", 
    name: "Muhammad", 
    family: "Rifqi" 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **function.php/query1** but your file name is **function_query.php**

Try this

```
 $('#btn-save').on('click',function(e) {

  $.post(base_url + "function_query.php/query1", {}, function(res) {
          alert('Save!');

        });
  });
```

and Also remove **$connection** from function and use that inside the function

```
<?php 
    $connection = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root","","mydb");
    function query1($data){
       //my query
    }

    function query2($data){
      //my query
    }
?>
```

You can also try this

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url:base_url + "function_query.php/query1",
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        contentType:'application/json',
        data:JSON.stringify({your data will goes here })
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I have updated my script first try this then let me know

Comment: Okay so you want to pass data as well

Comment: yeah i want to pass data as well

Comment: bottom script may be helpful try that

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle the request for function call.

**function_query.php**

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root","","mydb");

if(isset($_REQUEST['query1']))
   query1();
else if(isset($_REQUEST['query2']))
   query2();

function query1(){
   //my query
}

function query2(){
  //my query
}
?>
```

and in Your mypage.php put filename.php?functionname.....

mypage.php

Save

```
 $('#btn-save').on('click',function(e) {

  $.post(base_url + "function_query.php?query1", {}, function(res) {
          alert('Save!');

        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
<button id="btn-save"> Save </button>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#btn-save').on('click',function(e) {
      $.post("test1.php?func=query1", {a:'abc'}, function(res) {
          alert(res);
        });
      });
   </script>
```

and php looks like this

```
$_GET['func']();
function query1(){
   //my query
   echo $_POST['a'];
   echo 'yyy';
}

function query2(){
  //my query
  echo 'nnn';
}
echo 'no';
```